# how to make a unsorted version of this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, shuffle

###### This code to print a binary truth table how could I  change it to print random  binrary number of the same size

```
     N = 4

    with open('input.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(f'{bin(i)[2:]:>0{N}}\n' for i in range(2**N))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code slightly:

```
data = range(2**N)
with open('input.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(f'{bin(i)[2:]:>0{N}}\n' for i in data)
```

For a small number like `N = 4`, you can just shuffle the list of numbers instead of using a `range`:

```
from random import shuffle

data = list(range(2**N))
shuffle(data)
with open('input.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(f'{bin(i)[2:]:>0{N}}\n' for i in data)
```

Starting with `N > 10` or so, you start running into problems with the randomness, since many permutations will not be possible given how a Mersenne Twister is constructed.

Comment: The original code using `writelines` would not actually realize any enormous strings in memory all at once. It's not properly documented, but `file.writelines(iterable)` does in fact operate as an optimized equivalent to `for item in iterable: file.write(item)` (precisely to avoid massive memory waste for no benefit). If the OP used a listcomp, it would waste a ton of memory, but the genexpr is sane.

Comment: Also, heads up, `shuffle` shuffles in place and returns `None`, so you gotta tweak that second example.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Rookie errors fixed. Don't know why I'm not thinking straight. Much appreciated.